# Add content items to 2sxc list

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

Is it possible to add all content items of a specified content type to a list without having to do it one by one?  (there are a lot of items!)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in this code fragment, but that leads to another question.

### Here is the code:

```
@{

         var allConsultants = CreateSource<EntityTypeFilter>();
         allConsultants.TypeName = "Consultant";

        var consultantsList = AsDynamic(@allConsultants.List);

   }     

   @functions{

    public static string GetTitle(ToSic.SexyContent.DynamicEntity theConsultant)
      {
        return theConsultant.FirstName + theConsultant.LastName;
      }

   }

   Consultants List:  @consultantsList<br/><br/>

       @foreach(var cont in consultantsList ){
        <div class="sc-element">
            @cont.FirstName @cont.LastName @GetTitle( cont )
        </div>
    }
```

---

Now my question:

I want to pass each item in the list (variable cont) to a function that examines the items fields and then returns a string.  Here, I just want to grab the first and last names and concatenate them.

But, while I can pass in the item cont as a ToSic.SexyContent.DynamicEntity, that seems not to pass in the structure, so I cannot access the fields as in .LastName.

So, how do I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

And

public static string GetTitle(T dynamic theConsultant)

does the trick!